# Do I need to define more strtok functions?

Tags: c

I want to run a command line argument to interpret a username, name, email, and home directory. I got the username part right but the rest is out of place. I don't know if I am placing the strtok function in the right place and each time I compile, it errors out "the variable is unused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <username>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  char *username = argv[1];

  FILE *passwd = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
  if (!passwd) {
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }

  char *line = NULL;
  size_t max_length = 0;
  ssize_t ret_val = 0;
  char line_copy[1000];

  while ((ret_val = getline(&line, &max_length, passwd)) > 0) {
    strncpy(line_copy, line, 999);

    char *user = strtok(line_copy, ":");
    if (strcmp(user, username) == 0) {
      char *name = strtok(NULL, ":");
      char *email = strtok(NULL, ":");
      char *home_dir = strtok(NULL, ":");

      printf("user: %s\n", user);
      printf("name: %s\n", name);
      printf("email: %s\n", email);
      printf("home directory: %s\n", home_dir);
    }
  }

  fclose(passwd);
  passwd = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "variable is unused" isn't an error; it is a warning.

Comment: What variable does it say is unused?

Comment: The fields in `/etc/passwd` are `username:password:uid:gid:name:homedir:shell`. You're putting the password in `name`, the uid in `email`, and the gid in `home_dir`.  You need some extra calls to `strtok()` to skip over the fields you don't care about.

Comment: `strtok` never returns zero-length tokens, but zero-length fields are normal in `/etc/passwd`, so perhaps it's not the best idea to use `strtok`.

Comment: Instead of `strtok()`, which indeed is not a good choice for parsing `passwd` lines on account of not supporting zero-length fields, you could consider applying [`strcspn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn) to the job.  It will take a little restructuring, since `strcspn()` will only help you discover the lengths of the fields -- it will not replace deliminators with string terminators, nor *directly* provide pointers to the beginnings of the strings.

Comment: On a BSD- or GNU-derived system, you can use [strsep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)

Comment: /etc/passwd is NOT "user input", therefore (can't believe I'm suggesting this...) a single `fscanf()` properly done would serve far better than `strtok()`... Learn how to use the '*' specifier to "read but not assign" a field.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The structure of `/etc/passwd` varies depending on the system (see `passwd(5)` - `man 5 passwd` in your terminal). In order to parse the file manually, and in order for us to accurately help you, all parties need to know the exact format defined by your system. Note: There's nothing wrong with wanting to solve this problem yourself, as an exercise, but know that your system surely provides an interface to the password database. POSIX systems provide [`<pwd.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pwd.h.html).

Comment: For general POSIX use, you probably want to use [getpwent](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) rather than reading /etc/passwd directly.  You can use fgetpwent if you're getting the entries from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Linux /etc/passwd contains the colon separated fields login name, password, user id, group id, user name, home directory and shell.   You have call `strtok()` for the fields you want to skip, and there is no email field:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <username>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *username = argv[1];

    FILE *passwd = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
    if (!passwd) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t max_length = 0;
    ssize_t ret_val;
    while ((ret_val = getline(&line, &max_length, passwd)) > 0) {
        if (strcmp(username, strtok(line, ":")) == 0) {
            strtok(NULL, ":"); // password
            strtok(NULL, ":"); // uid
            strtok(NULL, ":"); // gid
            char *name = strtok(NULL, ":");
            char *home_dir = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("user: %s\n", username);
            printf("name: %s\n", name);
            printf("home directory: %s\n", home_dir);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(passwd);
    return 1;
}
```

Consider using `getpwnam()` instead:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <username>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    struct passwd *pw = getpwnam(argv[1]);
    if(!pw)
        return 1;

    printf("user: %s\n", pw->pw_name);
    printf("name: %s\n", pw->pw_gecos);
    printf("home directory: %s\n", pw->pw_dir);
}
```